# my terminal is returning a syntax error in my sass file inside vue.js and i cant figure this out

Tags: vue.js, sass

Compiled with problems:X

> ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[3]!./node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss)

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: expected "{".
> ╷
> 4 │ var content = require("!!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss");
> │                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ^
> ╵
> src\App.vue 4:221  root stylesheet.

here's my app.vue file
here is my vue.js

```html
<template>
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </nav>
  <router-view />
</template>

<style lang='scss'>
/* write SCSS here */
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

i tried  removing my styles and adding it back .

Comment: Maybe try double quote for the `scss` part.

Comment: Try to remove parts of your style until it works, so you can identify where the problem is.

Comment: I tried removing  all styles and I'm still getting a webpack issue this time .

Comment: Do you have any other sass stylesheet In your project?

Comment: no but, i solved already